# How to sort array in order to manage highest string length on top?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am new in php and i have an array like below

```html
$sv = array(
      "my name is john", // length 15
      "i am living in london from my childwood", // length 39
      "i am 13 years old", // length 17
      "i like to become software engineer in future" // length 44
);
```

Now i want to try to keep highest length value on top position in my array
and lowest in the bottom of the array.

and my output will be

```html
Array
(
  [0] => i like to become software engineer in future
  [1] => i am living in london from my childwood
  [2] => i am 13 years old
  [3] => my name is john
)
```

If anyone can know the answer then please share it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311003/how-do-i-sort-an-array-by-string-length-then-by-value-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try

```html
usort($sv, create_function('$a,$b','return strlen($b) - strlen($a);'));
```

You can get further reference from this link

[How-to-sort-array-as-per-text-length-of-value?](http://www.questionnanswer.com/questions/view_question/140/category_list:2/How-to-sort-array-as-per-text-length-of-value?)