# PHP array combination with Left to Right order

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have a PHP array that looks like this

```
$alphabet= array('a','b','c')
```

$alphabet is a input i need a result like $result

Expected output:

```
$result= array(
  [0]=> "a"
  [1]=> "b"
  [2]=> "c"
  [3]=> "ab"
  [4]=> "ac"
  [5]=> "bc"
  [6]=> "abc"
)
```

Note:
here, I would not like sorting to use.
Thanks!

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: $alphabet is a given input and I want a result $results

Comment: Please update your question with, well,.. your specific question. What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311003/how-do-i-sort-an-array-by-string-length-then-by-value-in-php

Comment: I was about to post answer for your combination array, you closed it

Answer (score 0):

Use [usort](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61047ac46a9763c1fe8426ace031fe695b68d434) and costum sort function:

```
$array = array("a", "bc", "bb", "aa", "cc", "bb");

function sortByValueLength($a, $b)
{
    $aLength = mb_strlen($a, 'utf-8');
    $bLength = mb_strlen($b, 'utf-8');
    if ($aLength == $bLength) {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }

    return $aLength - $bLength;
}

usort($array, 'sortByValueLength');

var_export($array);
```

Example result [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61047ac46a9763c1fe8426ace031fe695b68d434)

Comment: Question is not related to sort I think